# Put an empty field in peewee union select

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I'm try to select two table that have some common field. in raw MySQL query, i can write this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.username, t1.date FROM table1 as 't1' UNION SELECT t2.id, "const_txt", t2.date FROM table2  as 't2'
```

In that query ,the `username` field is not in table2 and I set `const_txt` instead.

So, in peewee, i want to union two table that have the same above situation.

```
class PeeweeBaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = my_db

class Table1(PeeweeBaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    username = CharField(255)
    date = DateTimeField()
    #other fields ...

class Table2(PeeweeBaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    date = DateTimeField()
    #other fields ...
```

and then , union two model. something like this:

```
u = (
    Table1(
        Table1.id,
        Table1.username,
        Table1.date
    ).select() 
    | 
    Table2(
        Table2.id,
        "const_text_instead_real_field_value",
        Table2.date
    ).select()
).select().execute()
```

But the `const_text` is not accepted by a field and ignore in result query.

the question is: How can I define a field that does not exist in my table and set it manually in query?

(And I prefer not using SQL() function.)

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use SQL() in SELECT statement.

```
u = (
    Table1(
        Table1.id,
        Table1.username,
        Table1.date
    ).select() 
    | 
    Table2(
        Table2.id,
        SQL(" '' AS username "),
        Table2.date
    ).select()
).select().execute()
```

Comment: This is good... but as I said before, I want another way except SQL (). But thank u again.

Comment: This is exactly what the `SQL` function is for.

Comment: @Reza-S4, just to clarify a bit, what type of API would you rather see than `SQL`?

Comment: @coleifer I test many other ways such as replacing a empty instance of CharField() instead SQL() function. But doesn't work. I think that maybe another function help me. Because I tested SQL() before.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I don't understand why you don't want to use `SQL()`. Is there a reason?

Comment: @coleifer , I think @Reza-S4 want other way to solve this problem, but i think use `SQL()` the only way for this problem

Comment: @coleifer, the peewee is a great and flexible orm and I thought it have another function to provide this automatically.so it seems the SQL() is the only solution for my problem at this time. Thanks all...